# ClassCastException when casting Drawable to BitmapDrawable

Tags: android

The following code causes ClassCastException on Android 8, 9 & 10. But not on Android 5, 6 & 7.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) aDrawable).getBitmap();
```

---

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: so what? It means that aDrawable is not BitmapDrawable on new sdks. You havent said where it comes from, so it hard to say what really happens. Check it real type with a debugger or in error message.

Comment: please read comments of answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036187/3947321

Comment: BitmapDrawable is derived from Drawable in Android 29.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417469/unable-to-convert-vector-drawable-to-bitmap-drawable-in-android

Comment: @RujulGandhi Thank you. I need to change the Drawable (Apps icons) to a BitmapDrawable so I can resize it and show it in a GridView. Is there a method to resize a Drawable as Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap)? or How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?